# How to take one column out of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, opencsv

THIS PROGRAM IMPORTS A DATAFRAME AND THEN ATTEMPTS TO EXTRACT ONE COLUMN HOWEVER I RECEIVE AN EROR WHEN I TRY TO EXTRACT ONE COLUMN (THE OPEN COLUMN)

import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.**version**)

## IMPORT LIBRARIES

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()


apple_all_stock_data = pd.read_csv('apple_all_stock_data.csv') 

apple_all_stock_data.head()
```

Date    Close/Last  Volume  Open    High    Low
0   9/25/2020   $112.28 149981400   $108.43 $112.44 $107.67
1   9/24/2020   $108.22 167743300   $105.17 $110.25 $105
2   9/23/2020   $107.12 150718700   $111.62 $112.11 $106.77
3   9/22/2020   $111.81 183055400   $112.68 $112.86 $109.16
4   9/21/2020   $110.08 195713800   $104.54 $110.19 $103.10
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
122 4/2/2020    $61.23  165933960   $60.09  $61.29  $59.23
123 4/1/2020    $60.23  176218560   $61.63  $62.18  $59.78
124 3/31/2020   $63.57  197002000   $63.90  $65.62  $63
125 3/30/2020   $63.70  167976440   $62.69  $63.88  $62.35
126 3/27/2020   $61.94  204216600   $63.19  $63.97  $61.76
127 rows × 6 columns

## HERE I ATTEMPT TO TAKE ONE COLUMN OUT OF THE DATAFRAME BUT ERRORS RESULT

```
apple_open_price = apple_all_stock_data[['Open']].values
```

#I GET THE ERROR BELOW WHEN I RUN THE LINE ABOVE:
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 apple_open_price = apple_all_stock_data[['Open']].values

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
1638             if missing == len(indexer):
1639                 axis_name = self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)
-> 1640                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
1641
1642             # We (temporarily) allow for some missing keys with .loc, except in

KeyError: "None of [Index(['Open'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Answer (score 1):

you can extract the column using the iloc method, like this:

```
apple_open_price = apple_all_stock_data.iloc[:, 3].values
```

The colon will indicate the lines and the number after the comma the respective column, remembering the first column starts at 0.

In pandas we have two very interesting ways to rescue the data we want, they are:

- loc
- iloc

Basically the two methods are used to rescue data, but they have different characteristics when we are going to use them.

The loc method is primarily based on column labels, but we can use it with a Boolean array as well. The method works like this:

```
df.loc [<lines>, <columns>]
```

with it we can combine logical operators to get the result we want, for example:

```
df.loc[(df['Superstar']*100) >= 10]
```

with this example, we can filter athletes who are likely to be Superstars greater than or equal to 10% on a dataframe on the performance of athletes.

while the iloc indexer is somewhat simpler, it selects by integers of the lines, arrays or by slice. We can conclude that iloc selects rows and columns by numbers, this is a good definition for the resource.

for more information you can see at:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html